# How to check Flash Player installed or not Using Javascript without any embeded library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know by using SWFObject library ,we can findout Flash player installed or not. But without any External library , Its possible get Flash player installed or not using jquery.It should work in Major browsers(Chrome,Firefox,IE)

Comment: dupe http://goo.gl/F9snx

Comment: You might want to paste the SWFObject library directly into your HTML head to avoid a physical second JavaScript file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWF Object Library they wrote codings to check plugins and Activex Objects.
The following if condition used to check plugins

```
 if (typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") {
               var ab = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"].description;
                if (ab && !(typeof navigator.mimeTypes != "undefined" && navigator.mimeTypes[q] && !navigator.mimeTypes[q].enabledPlugin)) {

                }
            }
```

The following if condition used to check ActiveX

```
if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
                    try {
                        var ad = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
                        if (ad) {
                            ab = ad.GetVariable("$version");
                            if (ab) {

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Z) {}
                }
```

The above code written in SWF object library.Now i got one doubt ,Plugin condition will work in all the browsers but Activex will work only in IE.[SWF Object library will work in all the browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147835/swf-object-library-will-work-in-all-the-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: not without a serious amount of headaches.

**Long answer**: SWFObject is also there to deal with all the little browser quirks; mapping them manually would take you longer than just using it, and your version will most likely not be as optimized.

A quick patch:

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
  var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if(fo) hasFlash = true;
} catch(e) {
   if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
}
```

This will try invoking the IE ActiveX version (IE6-7-8), and failing that, will look at the known mimetimes of the browser for SWF's mimetype. If it is there, you *might* have flash.