# SWF Object library will work in all the browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
            if (typeof t.plugins != D && typeof t.plugins[S] == r) {
                ab = t.plugins[S].description;
                if (ab && !(typeof t.mimeTypes != D && t.mimeTypes[q] && !t.mimeTypes[q].enabledPlugin)) {
                    T = true;
                    X = false;
                    ab = ab.replace(/^.*\s+(\S+\s+\S+$)/, "$1");
                    ag[0] = parseInt(ab.replace(/^(.*)\..*$/, "$1"), 10);
                    ag[1] = parseInt(ab.replace(/^.*\.(.*)\s.*$/, "$1"), 10);
                    ag[2] = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(ab) ? parseInt(ab.replace(/^.*[a-zA-Z]+(.*)$/, "$1"), 10) : 0
                }
            } else {
                if (typeof O.ActiveXObject != D) {
                    try {
                        var ad = new ActiveXObject(W);
                        if (ad) {
                            ab = ad.GetVariable("$version");
                            if (ab) {
                                X = true;
                                ab = ab.split(" ")[1].split(",");
                                ag = [parseInt(ab[0], 10), parseInt(ab[1], 10), parseInt(ab[2], 10)]
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Z) {}
                }
            }
            return {
                w3: aa,
                pv: ag,
                wk: af,
                ie: X,
                win: ae,
                mac: ac
            }
        }()
```

The above code used in swf object library .They checking plugin and ActiveX object written in jquery.Activex will work in IE only.**My doubt is whether it will work in all the browsers?if it is yes means ,how its working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why shouldn't it work? The check for ActiveX is conditional as well as the access to the ActiveX object catched in case of an error.

So any browser that does not support non-IE behavior (that is, all except IE ;)), will be handled by the `else`.

BTW: the latest version in the repos has the code a little differently structrued

```
.... }
else if (typeof win.ActiveXObject != UNDEF) {
   try {
       var a = new ActiveXObject(SHOCKWAVE_FLASH_AX);
       if (a) { // a will return null when ActiveX is disabled
          d = a.GetVariable("$version");
          if (d) {
             ie = true; // cascaded feature detection for Internet Explorer
             d = d.split(" ")[1].split(",");
             playerVersion = [parseInt(d[0], 10), parseInt(d[1], 10), parseInt(d[2], 10)];
            }
        }

   catch(e) {}
}
```

It's not an `else` anymore but an `else if` (again with a try-catch). The most common case is coverd before hand. They simply check for all the plugins loaded by the browser as reported by `navigator.plugins`. Since this is the way to do it, most browsers will never enter the `else if` part.

To get some information about `navigator.plugins`, check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.plugins). This is a browser thing and available in all browsers (except the usual IEs, but the technique from the code above will take care of this). This will always be "plugins". If you try to access it differently e.g. "plugin", you will get an error since it is not defined.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by mentioning jQuery. This is vanilla JS, so there is no jQuery used. We used this library quite often and I can asure you, it is stable and well tested.

Comment: I dont know about navigator.plugin.So pls explain about that and Suppose i not plugined ,then it navigator.plugins will work?

Comment: @P.PrabhakaranB.E check my update. This is a browser side thing that will always be there.